# How to find a index from a two dimensional array

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is print the largest number within a two dimensional array and it's index location. I'm able to find the largest number, but I can't seem to figure out how to print it's index location. Anyway, here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{4, 44, 5, 7, 63, 1}, {7, 88, 31, 95, 9, 6}, {88, 99, 6, 5, 77, 4}};

    double max = arr[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] > max) {
                max = arr[i][j];

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(i + j); //No idea what I should be doing here, just trying out everything I can think of
```

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you should consistently get 2 * arr.length as the final value. That isn't what you are probably looking for. It looks like you want to know the coordinates for the max value. To do this, you'll need to cache the values of the indexes and then use them later:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = {{4, 44, 5, 7, 63, 1}, {7, 88, 31, 95, 9, 6}, {88, 99, 6, 5, 77, 4}};
    int tmpI = 0;
    int tmpJ = 0;
    double max = arr[0][0];
    // there are some changes here. in addition to the caching
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int[] inner = arr[i];
        // caches inner variable so that it does not have to be looked up
        // as often, and it also tests based on the inner loop's length in
        // case the inner loop has a different length from the outer loop.
        for (int j = 0; j < inner.length; j++) {
            if (inner[j] > max) {
                max = inner[j];
                // store the coordinates of max
                tmpI = i; tmpJ = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
    // convert to string before outputting:
    System.out.println("The (x,y) is: ("+tmpI+","+tmpJ+")");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was freaking out the past two hours.....
I actually tried something similar to the tmpI and tmpJ thing, but didn't work out. The difference between what I did and yours was that I didn't set the value to 0 in the beginning.

Comment: @MNX1024 Happens to all of us.

Comment: Just realized you edit the codes. What you had originally was what I was looking for. What I posted here was just a test I'm doing to get the right code working before I modify it and use it in another program. Anyway, I have another question. If I were to put this into a method and I want to return both i and j in a single return statement. Is it possible? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: @MNX1024 Java only allows for one return value.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with your array dimensions! The second for-statement most of you have is wrong. It should go to up to  **arr[i].length**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] > max) {
            max = arr[i][j];
            tmpI = i; tmpJ = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store i, j whenever you update max.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a two-dimensional array, therefore you need to know both indexes. Adding them together won't do because you lose which-is-which. How about this:

```
System.out.println("[" + i + "][" + j + "]");
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be if you wanted a single index into a flatten array:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
        int[][] arr = {{4, 44, 5, 7, 63, 1}, {7, 88, 31, 95, 9, 6}, {88, 99, 6, 5, 77, 4}};
            int[] flattened = new int[6*3]; // based off above
            int maxIndex = 0;
            double max = arr[0][0];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                    flattened[i + j] = arr[i][j];
                    if (arr[i][j] > max) {
                        max = arr[i][j];
                        maxIndex  = i+j;
                    }
                }
        }
    System.out.println(max);
    System.out.println(flattened [maxIndex]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[][] arr = {{4, 44, 5, 7, 63, 1}, {7, 88, 31, 95, 9, 6}, {88, 99, 6, 5, 77, 4}};

int max = arr[0][0];
int maxI = 0, maxJ = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] > max) {
            max = arr[i][j];
            maxI = i;
            maxJ = j;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(max);
System.out.println(maxI + "," + maxJ);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//C++ code
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
vector<int> b;
vector<int> c;
int Func(int a[][10],int n)
{
    int max;
    max=a[0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                    if(a[i][j]>max)
                    {
                                   max=a[i][j];
                                   b.push_back(i);
                                   c.push_back(j);
                                   }

                    }
                    }
                    b.push_back(0);
                    c.push_back(0);
                    return max;
                    }
    void display(int a[][10],int n)
    {
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                    cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                    }
                    }

int main()
{
    int a[10][10],n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                    cin>>a[i][j];
                    }
                    }
                    cout<<endl;
                    display(a,n);
                    cout<<endl;
                    cout<<Func(a,n)<<" is the greatest "<<endl;
                    if(b.size()==1&&c.size()==1)
                    {
                                            cout<<"Location is (1,1)"<<endl;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                 b.erase(b.end() - 1);
                                                 c.erase(c.end() - 1);
                    cout<<"Location is "<<"("<<b.back()+1<<","<<c.back()+1<<")"<<endl;
                    }
                    return 0;
                    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you posted C++ code on a java question unless you just want to confuse him further...

Comment: This is a java question. In the future, please answer java questions with either a general concept or java.

Answer (score 1):

You're just adding the indices i and j together and then printing it to the screen. Since you're running throug the entire loop it's just going to be equal to 2*arr.length-2. What you need to do is store the values of i and j when you encounter a new max value.

For example:

```
int[][] arr = {{4, 44, 5, 7, 63, 1}, {7, 88, 31, 95, 9, 6}, {88, 99, 6, 5, 77, 4}};

int max = arr[0][0]; //dunno why you made it double when you're dealing with integers
int max_row=0;
int max_column=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] > max) {
            max = arr[i][j];
            max_row=i;
            max_column=j;

        }
    }
System.out.println("The max is: "+max+" at index ["+max_row+"]["+max_column+"]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure that you implement effective algorithm, but why you just don't save indices i,j in another variables when you set max.
This is very simple.

```
if (arr[i][j] > max) {
    max = arr[i][j];
    maxX = i;
    maxY = j;
}
```

FYI If you want look at "insertion sorting" algorithms if you want better implementation.