# How to print all indexes of a multi dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

How to print all the indexes of an array if only its dimensions are given. I have done it recursively but unable to do it in iterations. I started but have only gone this far..

```
public static void print(int[] lengthOfDimension) {

            int[] index = new int[lengthOfDimension.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfDimension.length; i++) {
                for (int j = lengthOfDimension.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                    for (int m = lengthOfDimension[j] - 1; m > -1; m--) {
                        index[j] = m;
                        for (int l = 0; l < index.length; l++)
                            System.out.print(index[l] + " ");
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    index[j - 1] = lengthOfDimension[lengthOfDimension.length - i
                            - 1]
                            - i - 1;
                }

                // index[i] = lengthOfDimension[i] - 1;
            }
        }
```

Have run my code for this array: int a[] = { 3, 2 ,3};

it gives following output:

```
0 0 2 
0 0 1 
0 0 0 

0 1 0 
0 0 0 

2 0 2 
2 0 1 
2 0 0 

2 1 0 
2 0 0 

0 0 2 
0 0 1 
0 0 0 

0 1 0 
0 0 0
```

Expected Output is:

```
for a[] = {3,2,3}

    0 0 0
    0 0 1
    0 0 2
    0 1 0
    0 1 1
    0 1 2
    1 0 0
    1 0 1
    1 0 2
    1 1 0
    1 1 1
    1 1 2
    2 0 0
    2 0 1
    2 0 2
    2 1 0
    2 1 1
    2 1 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a index from a two dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535556/how-to-find-a-index-from-a-two-dimensional-array)

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: For a = {2,2}
0 0
0 1

1 0
1 1

for a[] = {3,2,3}
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2

0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2

1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2

1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2

2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2

Comment: Please add the expected output to the question, not as a comment

Comment: I have added Expected output in question at end as well @Felk

Comment: ... as an image :(

Comment: I don't really see a pattern in this expected output (not if `{3,2,3}` is the only data it receives). Can we also have an image of the requirement, maybe?

Comment: Do you want to do it only for 3d arrays or it can be anything like 4d 5d or ...nd?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Sir, please see again, there is a pattern, its about all the indexes of the array. And I am new to stackoverflow, I have removed the image now if it bothers you so much. Cheers.

Comment: Yeah.There is a pattern

Comment: @Debabrata, it it whould print indexes as it said, then where is all-zeros page in expected output?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov in a 3d array there would be only one element index of which would be(0,0,0)

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, its nd array.

Comment: @Debabrata, ah, yes, you're correct

Comment: @parik nope the answer you suggested is about 2d array, and here its about nd

Comment: @Rosellene in your expected output i don't think last three lines should be there

Comment: @Debabrata your are right, corrected, I did it in haste

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you're trying to generate all possible permutations of indexes into a 1-dimensional array of a given length.

There's some confusion in the comments between the dimensionality of the array and the dimensionality of the data stored in the array. For example, `int[] a1 = {3,2,3}` is a 1-d array storing data that can be interpreted as a point in 3-d space. On the other hand, `int[][] a2` declares a 2-d array.

The technique used below to generate all permutations works very much like the old odometers you find in cars. Starting from the lowest position we keep incrementing the index by 1 and checking if it should roll over. If so we reset it to 0 and carry on. If not then we have a new permutation.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a[] = { 3, 2 ,3};
    indexPermutations(a);
}

public static void indexPermutations(int[] arr)
{
    int n = arr.length;
    int[] idx = new int[n];

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(idx));

        // generate the next permutation
        int i = n-1;
        for (; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            idx[i] += 1;
            if (idx[i] < n) break;                  
            idx[i] = 0;
        }

        // if the first index wrapped around then we're done
        if (i < 0) break;               
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 2]
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 2, 0]
[0, 2, 1]
[0, 2, 2]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[2, 0, 0]
[2, 0, 1]
[2, 0, 2]
[2, 1, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: here for dimension {3,2,3}  all permutations could only be 3*2*3=18.How did you come up with  27 permutations.in your code `if (idx[i] < n) break` here you have bug.n is not always same.It can be 3 or 2 or again 3 depending which element you are iterating